# If $f,g$ are continuous and $g$ is $1$-periodic, $\int_0^1 f(x)g(nx)dx \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \int_0^1 f \int_0^1 g$

Tags: integration, limits, continuity, lebesgue-integral, periodic-functions

Let $f,g\in C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ where $g(x+1)=g(x) \; \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that
\begin{equation} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^1 f(x)g(nx)dx=\int_0^1f(x)dx \int_0^1g(x)dx . \end{equation}

Comment: I have really no idea how to start! I have thought to pass the limit inside by applying Beppo-Levi's theorem but I don't think it would be fruitful...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*To complement [LeBtz's excellent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1888359/75808) above, let's try a more heuristic way of figuring out what to do. This may not be the shortest, but should (i) give an intuition of what is going on; and (ii) show that is it not "magic" with the proof coming out of the blue, but that there is some process to arrive at the result.*

---

Since the assumption on $g$ is $1$-periodicity, we want to make appear things like $g(u+k)$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$, so that we can simplify. So let us break $[0,1]$ in many segments of length $\frac{1}{n}$, so that $g(nx)$ becomes something we want:
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(x)g(nx)dx
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{\frac{k}{n}}^{\frac{k+1}{n}} f(x)g(nx)dx
= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} f\left(u+\frac{k}{n}\right)g\left(n\left(u+\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)du \\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} f\left(u+\frac{k}{n}\right)g\left(nu+k\right)du
=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} f\left(u+\frac{k}{n}\right)g(nu)du
\end{align}
$$
That's good, we got somewhere. Not quite there, but still... we can get a little more done now by swtiching integral and sum, and observing that after simplification the term $g(nu)$ does not depend on the summation index $k$ anymore:
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(x)g(nx)dx
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} f\left(u+\frac{k}{n}\right)g(nu)du
= \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} du \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  f\left(u+\frac{k}{n}\right)g(nu)\\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} du\, g(nu) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  f\left(u+\frac{k}{n}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Not too bad. Let's continue — eventually, we want integrals from $0$ to $1$, so let us switch back *via* a change of variables:
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 f(x)g(nx)dx
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} du\, g(nu) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  f\left(u+\frac{k}{n}\right)
= \int_{0}^{1} dx\, g(x) \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  f\left(\frac{x}{n}+\frac{k}{n}\right)
\end{align}
$$

*That* looks promising. Why? Well, if the last term had been $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)$ instead, we would have had a Riemann sum for $f$, whose limit as $n\to \infty$ is exactly $\int_0^1 f$... this is nice. But there is that extra $\frac{x}{n}$ which is preventing that from directly applying: this is where the (uniform, since on a bounded closed interval) continuity of $f$ should come into play, as $\frac{x}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$.

- By the above, 
  $$\begin{align}
  \int_{0}^{1} dx\, g(x) \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
  =
  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\int_{0}^{1} g(x)dx
  \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx \int_{0}^{1} g(x)dx
  \end{align} \tag{1}
  $$
- Let us control the difference, call it $\Delta_n$:
  $$\begin{align}
  \Delta_n &= \left\lvert \int_{0}^{1} dx\, g(x) \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)
  - 
  \int_{0}^{1} dx\, g(x) \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  f\left(\frac{x}{n}+\frac{k}{n}\right)
   \right\rvert
  \\&=
  \left\lvert \int_{0}^{1} dx\, g(x) \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  \left( f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) - f\left(\frac{x}{n}+\frac{k}{n}\right) \right)
   \right\rvert \\
  &\leq \int_{0}^{1} dx\, \lvert g(x)\rvert \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  \left\lvert f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) - f\left(\frac{x}{n}+\frac{k}{n}\right)  \right\rvert
  \end{align}
  $$

  For convenience, write $\lVert g\rVert_\infty\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \max_{x\in[0,1]} \lvert g(x)\rvert$ (this exists, as $g$ is continuous). Fix any $\varepsilon > 0$, and — $f$ is uniformly continuous too — let $N_\varepsilon$ such that, for all $n\geq N_\varepsilon$, $\lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{\lVert g\rVert_\infty+1}$ whenever $x,y\in[0,1]$ satisfy $\lvert x-y\rvert \leq \frac{1}{n}$. *(The $+1$ is just to avoid dividing by zero if $g$ is identically zero.)*

  Then we are good: for any $n\geq N_\varepsilon$, since $\frac{x}{n} \leq \frac{1}{n}$, we get

  $$\begin{align}
  \Delta_n &\leq \int_{0}^{1} dx\, \lvert g(x)\rvert \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  \left\lvert f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) - f\left(\frac{x}{n}+\frac{k}{n}\right)  \right\rvert\\
  &\leq \int_{0}^{1} dx\, \lVert g\rVert_\infty \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  \frac{\varepsilon}{\lVert g\rVert_\infty+1}
  = \varepsilon \frac{\lVert g\rVert_\infty}{\lVert g\rVert_\infty+1}\\
  &< \varepsilon
  \end{align}$$
  and since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we just showed that $$\Delta_n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0. \tag{2}
  $$

Combining (1) and (2) gives the limit:

> $$
> \int_0^1 f(x)g(nx)dx = \int_{0}^{1} dx\, g(x) \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}  f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) +\Delta_n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx \int_{0}^{1} g(x)dx+0
> $$

Answer (score 9):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1f(x)g(nx)dx &= \frac 1n\int_0^n f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)g(x)dx = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_k^{k+1}f\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)g(x)dx  \\
&= \frac 1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1 f\left(\frac{x+k}{n}\right)g(x)dx.
\end{align}$$

Now use that for $n$ large enough by uniform continuity of $f$ and boundedness of $g$ we can get $f(\frac{x+k}{n})g(x)$ in an $\epsilon$-range of $f(\frac kn)g(x)$. Summed up and divided by $n$ we remain in an $\epsilon$-range if we replace $f(\frac{x+k}{n})$ in the integral by $f(\frac kn)$.

But then we have

$$ \frac 1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)g(x)dx =  \frac 1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\int_0^1g(x)dx.
$$

Take it from there.